# How to redirect to an arbitrary jsp from Struts action class?

Tags: java, struts

I have scenario like login page where when the user access any privileged page, it should redirect  to login page and after login it should get redirected back to the original page. I can pass the original page as query parameter. However how can redirect to the original page from the LoginAction class?

Comment: are you looking for `return mapping.findForward()` method

Comment: @Rejeev, don't forget to accept answer which solved your problem.

Comment: yeah, I will accept the answer once i have a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `response.sendRedirect()` and return null from your action, or return an instance of [ActionRedirect](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionRedirect.html) from your action.

Comment: Can I return an instance ActionRedirct from the execute method of the Action class? The return type of the execute is 'String' isn't it?

Comment: Are you using Struts2? I thought you were using Struts1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173846/struts2-how-to-do-dynamic-url-redirects for Struts2