# Struts2 redirect in new tab

Tags: redirect, struts2

I'm developing a struts2 project.
In my `struts.xml`, I have a redirect to a dynamic page `http://myurl.de/2012-07-20.html`
like described here: [How to do dynamic URL redirects in Struts 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173846/struts2-how-to-do-dynamic-url-redirects).

But I want the new page to be shown in a new tab. Is there a way to do this in the `struts.xml` file?

I found some JavaScript solutions but I would prefer to do it in the `struts.xml`

Comment: No, there isn't--a redirect is just that, a redirect, to the client (e.g., a browser). There's no HTTP protocol that says "redirect but open a new window".

Comment: Take help of javascript it will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

when you call the url that should redirect to new pop up window, by using `window.open()` in javaScript. or by specifying `target="_blank"` in the form tag, this will open the redirected page in new pop up window. about the new tab, you cannot control `target="_blank"` will open in new popup or new tab because this is decided by the browser you are using whether it is IE, FF or chrome.

you can configure your browser to open in new tab instead of new window. through the browser options