# struts2 action redirect to "outside" url

Tags: redirect, struts2, action, httprequest

i need my action to be able to redirect to outside url address, lets say for exemple http://google.com

Right now i have:

```
<default-action-ref name="home" />
<global-results>
  <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${targetUrl}</result>
</global-results>
```

if in targetUrl i have http://google.com my action will call home page and it iwll not redirect to google.

I saw the similar question here
[How to do dynamic URL redirects in Struts 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173846/struts2-how-to-do-dynamic-url-redirects)
but I can see that only the last part of url is being used as a destination for the redirection.

can you please help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a specific action from an interceptor I did the following:

```
response.sendRedirect("specificAction.action");
return null;
```

No need for global results in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your question.
From the Action class from you returning the redirect the targetUrl should be member variable for the class and should have public getter and setter.

```
public class YourAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String targetUrl;

    public String execute() {
         return "redirect";
    }

    public String getTargetUrl() {
        return targetUrl;
    }

    public void setTargetUrl(String targetUrl) {
        this.targetUrl = targetUrl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [Http Header](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/httpheader-result.html) result type. That will work because a redirect instruction to the browser is simply a status code plus 'Location' header.

```
<result name="startCheckout" type="httpheader">
    <param name="status">303</param>
    <param name="headers.location">${externalUrl}</param>
</result>
```