# redirect from action to external url in Struts2

Tags: url, redirect, struts2, action

I am trying similar thing as of this question

[redirect external url in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854429/redirect-external-url-in-browser)

but it is not working with me at all.

Action code:

```
    public String getMail(){
        try {  //some code

            url = accessToken.getCallbackUrl();
            if(url != null){

                return "redirect";
            }

            return "input";

        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            return "input";
        }
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
```

Struts.xml

```
    <action name="getMail" method="getMail"
                  class="test.MailAction">
                <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
                <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${url}</result>
    </action>
```

I wrote setter-getter also for url.

and when I am trying to manually write this url in browser then it is working perfectly.But, automatically it is not redirecting

Comment: Don't use `getSOMETHING` for a method that is not a `Getter` :/ BTW, which error are you hitting ?

Comment: It is not showing any error. It just stops before **return   "redirect";** statement.

Comment: Are you getting an url from your `accessToken.getCallbackUrl();` method?

Comment: Yes, I am getting url and when I am pasting this url on browser manually then it is working fine too.

Comment: So what do you mean by **It just stops before return "redirect"; statement**?

Comment: `if(url != null){
                   System.out.println(url);
                return "redirect";
            }`                                                              I wrote this. So it prints url on console and hangs there.Then I just copy that url from console and paste on browser and it works.

Comment: Hangs? So you are trying to say that return doesn't returns?

Comment: Yes, it is not returning anything