# Redirecting to another action with unknown amount of parameters in Struts 2

Tags: java, xml, redirect, struts2, ognl

I have a login action which after successful execution redirects to the previous page (I store the previous page in my session so I can fetch it later). In Struts2, I can find two ways to do this redirection:

```
    <action name="login" class="com.myapp.login.Login">
        <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${previousAction.requestURL}</result>   
    </action>
```

In this example, the `getPreviousAction().getRequestURL()` method (this is a selfmade method, its not native to Struts2) will be invoked and this will return the URL of the previous page as intended, for example:

```
somenamespace/index.action
```

There is also another type of redirection:

```xml
<action name="login" class="com.myapp.login.Login">
     <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">${previousAction.name}</param>
        <param name="namespace">/${previousAction.namespace}</param>
    </result>   
</action>
```

I want to use this `redirectAction result type because it is much cleaner. But, I have a problem when query parameters are part of the URL. For example:

```
somenamespace/index.action?name=john&age=50
```

I know I can add these params hardcoded in my `struts.xml`, but the problem is my login action should redirect to *any* previously invoked action, and I do not know beforehand which query parameters the previous actions had. This is different from the typical usecase where you know exactly to which action you're redirecting to

A very bad solution I found was adding *every* param possible (the collection of all params of all my actions in `struts.xml`) and then use the option:

```
<param name="suppressEmptyParameters">true</param>
```

Comment: better way to set your parameter in request scope and fetch them all in your next action

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/parameters-in-configuration-results.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save action name, namespace, and  parameters from the `ActionMapping`.

```
ActionMapping mapping = ServletActionContext.getActionMapping();
```

You can also save query string instead of parameter map.

```
String params = request.getQueryString();
```

To add parameters dynamically to `redirectAction` result you should use OGNL in a dynamic parameter.

```
<param name="actionName">${previousAction.name +'?'+ parameters}</param>
```

Supposed you have a getter for `parameters` and initialized it from session where you saved previous query string, action name, and namespace.

Comment: Great, in the documentation it looked like you could not provide additional parameters, only the name.