# How to redirect struts action with dynamic parameter

Tags: redirect, struts2, parameter-passing, action

I want to redirect action with parameter "id".

I used this code in struts.xml

```
<action name="register" class="com.framework.strust2.UserAffair">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">viewProfile</param>
            <param name="id">${id}</param>
        </result>
</action>
```

It works for action redirecting and parameter name id, but not parameter value ${id}. It only works with constant id, like;

```
 <param name="id">1</param>
```

Though I searched the solution of my problem, there is nothing case that matches what I needed. Pls.

Comment: in action class you should have to define id variable. can you put down your action class code so as to we can get a better idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struts2 - How to do dynamic URL redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173846/struts2-how-to-do-dynamic-url-redirects)

Comment: Awesome! thanks @Roman C. It finally works.

Answer (score 4):

For passing the parameter with action you should have to define that variable in action and if you are using model driven approach then that parameter should be in pojo i.e

it is your struts.xml action configuration.

```xml
<action name="register" class="com.framework.strust2.UserAffair">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">viewProfile</param>
        <param name="id">${id}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

so in you action class there should be variable sayaing id.
i.e

```java
class UserAffair{
 private int id;

 //setter and getter
}
```

and  if you are using model drivan then in your pojo there should be a variable saying id.

hope so this will help you a lot

Comment: I have already getter and setter in UserAffair class. If I set fixed "id" like: 1,2,3 and directly trigger viewProfile action, the parameter "id" can be printed out in jsp page.